How to resolve Firebase related swift compiler errors in Pod dependencies?
I have recently made a project in Flutter using Android Studio, with the goal to build the same app on IOS as well.
The android version of the app (apk/app bundle) works fine, (it is already uploaded in playstore). I never had issues when building the apk and everything worked fine.
When I finished building the app using my Windows computer and Android Studio, I switched to my old MacBook Air and tried to build the bundle for the ios (think it's called ipa bundle).
However, I keep getting the same compiler errors that point to this directory:
Pods/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal
These are the logs when I run flutter build ios
thalis@Thaliss-Air prosoxi_elegktes % flutter build ios
Building com.symplyapps.carefulcontrol for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team
in Xcode project: 86B99NQXZB
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           349.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit
code


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Consecutive declarations on a line must be
separated by ';'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatController.swift:33:26


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Expected declaration
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatController.swift:33:27


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Consecutive declarations on a line must be
separated by ';'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:32:26


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Expected declaration
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:32:27


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an
initializer
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:203:28


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an
initializer
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/Storage.swift:69:18


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an
initializer
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/Storage.swift:143:16


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find type 'any' in scope
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatController.swift:33:23


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored property 'storage' of 'Sendable'-conforming
class 'HeartbeatController' has non-sendable type '<<error type>>'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatController.swift:33:14


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Unable to infer complex closure return type; add
explicit type to disambiguate
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatController.swift:76:30


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Unable to infer complex closure return type; add
explicit type to disambiguate
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatController.swift:167:29


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored property 'userAgentPayloads' of
'Sendable'-conforming struct 'HeartbeatsPayload' has non-sendable type
'[HeartbeatsPayload.UserAgentPayload]'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatsPayload.swift:60:6


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find type 'any' in scope
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:32:23


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored property 'storage' of 'Sendable'-conforming
class 'HeartbeatStorage' has non-sendable type '<<error type>>'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:32:14


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored property 'encoder' of 'Sendable'-conforming
class 'HeartbeatStorage' has non-sendable type 'JSONEncoder'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:34:14


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored property 'decoder' of 'Sendable'-conforming
class 'HeartbeatStorage' has non-sendable type 'JSONDecoder'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:36:14


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored property 'queue' of 'Sendable'-conforming
class 'HeartbeatStorage' has non-sendable type 'DispatchQueue'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:38:14


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Value of type 'NSLock' has no member 'withLock'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:81:18


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Unable to infer complex closure return type; add
explicit type to disambiguate
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:81:27


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Value of type 'NSLock' has no member 'withLock'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/HeartbeatStorage.swift:112:27


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Stored property 'url' of 'Sendable'-conforming
class 'FileStorage' has non-sendable type 'URL'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/Storage.swift:39:14


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot infer contextual base in reference to
member 'atomic'
/Users/thalis/Dropbox/Flutter/prosoxi_elegktes/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreInternal/Fir
ebaseCore/Internal/Sources/HeartbeatLogging/Storage.swift:70:42


Encountered error while building for device.

What I don't understand is how this code can have error when it comes 'right out of the box' meaning that it's not hand written from me. It's added to my project when running the command pod install. I mistakenely thought I broke something when experimenting for the first time with building in ios and thus, I decided to delete the whole ios folder in my project and recreate it again using the command flutter create . --platforms ios.
When I ran this command, my dependencies where re-generated and I faced another error which said that:
I should target ios version 13 or higher in order for firebase to work
I did change the version in the Podfile and now it looks like this:
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

Rebuilding the project results in the same Swift compiler errors shown in the above log.
The answer is:
Why does this happen and what steps should I take in order to reslove this?
What I have already tried:

Running flutter clean, flutter pub get pod install and rebuilding with flutter build ios
Deleting the whole ios folder and recreating it from scratch

My specifications:

MacBook Air6,2 - 13inch, mid 2013
XCode version: 13.2.1 (13C100)
Target device does not seem to have an effect as selecting either ios Simulator or physical IPhone device produce the same error

Edit - Note:
I know nothing related to Swift. I have never written Swift - ios code.

you can follow this link : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/154423 from official github page

Update pods. If it doesn't help create issue in Firebase. Pods should be integrated without issues. If issues occurs it problem of podprovider.

@HardikMehta it's as if i did not already mention that I have tried to delete the whole ios folder which includes the Podfile.lock. It's as if I did not already search the web and come across the number 1 result of google. Completely unhelpful comment

ecent versions of Firebase require at least Xcode 15.2.

As Paul Beusterien noted - the problem lies in Xcode version in relation to the dependencies
Because I have an old mac, I could not figure out a solution (my model is unsupported for higher versions of Xcode/MacOS)
The solution for me is to patch the newest MacOS version through OpenCore software. Worked like a charm for me. Open Core Legacy Patcher
Note: If you happen to use this tool, make sure you usb flash drive is at least 32GB, preferrably 64GB
